# Google Cloud Custom Domains NameCheap - "WWW" not working

Tags: google-cloud-platform, namecheap, custom-domain

I have purchased a domain on https://www.namecheap.com/. I also have a Cloud Run service running on Google Cloud. I verified my domain on Google and I added it as a Custom Domain. In return Google gave me the DNS records[image: dns Records]

All I had to do was to go to  NameCheap and add these records which I did.
[image: ipv4]

[image: ipv6]

I can accces my site website like this https://abcd.com but not like this https://www.abcd.com with (WWW). Any ideea why?

Later Edit: here is the error
[image]

CURL error:
[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "can't access"?, What errors do you get?

Comment: Typically for cloud run you need to add both domains, www and non-www, in order for it to create the 2 ssl certs

Comment: In the Webmaster Central (https://www.google.com/webmasters/verification) I cannot verifiy the domain twice (with WWW and without) because it says it's already verified. When I go to Clodu Run - Add Maping I see only one domain(without WWW). And the documenttion says the same, that I should verify my domain once and it will work with WWW and without.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to have both the apex domain (`abcd.com`) as well as the `www.abcd.com` subdomain mapped to the same Cloud Run app you need to create **both** such mappings on the Cloud Run page.

[image: domain mappings]

You already have you apex domain mapped and the mapping produced a list of records you had to create with your DNS provider (A and AAAA records)

[image: apex mapping]

After creating this second mapping (`www.abcd.com`) Cloud Run will ask you create another (`CNAME`) DNS record (`www.abcd.com` -> `ghs.googlehosted.com`).

[image: www. mapping]

All together you have to have 8 A/AAAA records and 1 CNAME records with your DNS provider after you are done

[image: dns records]

After the CNAME record is created and verified, the certificate will be issued, and then you should be able to access your application with both apex and subdomain(s).

Comment: I tried to verify my www.abcd.com domain but for some reason the domain is no verified. I used the same method that as when I verified abcd.com with  TXT record from Webmaster Central. But now even after 2 hours is not working.

Comment: You don't need to separately verify www.abcf.com if you already have abcd.com verified. Instead when you are adding the mapping, choose the service and then your verified domain abcd.com and in the last field type www for subdomain.

Comment: I managed to do it. My issue was that after I initialy added the main domain I remmoved the TXT record. As a result when I was clicking on "add mapping" Google was asking me to verify a domain again, hence the confusion. Ading the TXT back on the dns record and verifing the domain again fixed the issue. Thank you for you answers.